# How zoom out increase the screen width?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have laptop screen with resolution 1366*768 pixels , that mean screen width is 1366 pixels and height is 768 pixels , that is fixed when i set my screen resolution to 1366*768, If i have a webpage  which have css property

```
 @media screen  and (max-width:1366px){
   //css1
 }
 @media screen and (min-width:1361px) and (max-width:1500px){
   //css2
 }
```

That mean if device 's screen has a `width` of `1366px` or lesser `css1` will apply to that page , and if the screen is larger than `1366px` then `css2` will be apply , . So for my laptop screen `css1` should be applied because it has screen width of 1366px .

At ZOOM:100% , this works fine , But if I zoom out , `css2` starts applying , I can't understand how this can be happen , my screen width is fixed, So how Zoom out  can increase my screen width ,  .

I become very confused , I am trying to understand this screen resolution, pixels, zoom,  for very long time now ,But can't really understand how they works ,  please help#

Comment: @k2a See this example here http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery  , and just zoom in and zoom out ,You will understand what i am saying, width of right section remain same but still the color will change

Answer (score 0):

Media queries limit the layout width and if this value is reached (for example by reducing the window, or when viewed on a device with the specified size) is already used by a different style.  that is how media queries should work.

Comment: i Understand when we reduce the window , But I am talking about when we zoom out how the screnn size is increased ,

Comment: from https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/
4.3. device-width

Value: <length>
Applies to: visual and tactile media types
Accepts min/max prefixes: yes
The ‘device-width’ media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device. For continuous media, this is the width of the screen. For paged media, this is the width of the page sheet size.

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom out you're increasing the viewport size. When media queries refer to `screen` they're talking about the browser's viewport width, not your physical screen's width.